# Homework: limit of $\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n(n+k)}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Determine the following limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots (n+n)} $$
**Idea #1**
the nth root could be rewritten as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n+n)!}{n!}} $$
Noticing that $n^{-1}$ is an infinitesimal, if the n-th root were bounded, the limit would be $0$.

But hoping that $\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n+n)!}{n!}}$ is bounded is a pipe dream, this clearly tends to $\infty$.

**Idea #2**
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left (\frac{1}{n}[(n+1)\ldots (n+n)]^\frac{1}{n}\right ) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left [-\ln n+\frac{1}{n}\left (\ln (n+1)+\ln (n+2)+\ldots +\ln (n+n) \right )\right ]$$
but trying to bring it to a common denominator doesn't help either, what I would have is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \left [-n\ln n+\ln (n+1)+\ldots +\ln 2+\ln n\right ]$$
Which doesn't bring me any closer to simplification.
The solution of this must something entirely different. I would like a hint/point me in the direction I should go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for 
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n^n}}. $$
By setting $a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n^n}$ we have:
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)n^n}{(n+1)(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{4n+2}{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$
hence:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{4}{e} $$
and that implies:
$$ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n^n}}=\color{red}{\frac{4}{e}}.$$

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: $(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n) = \frac{(2n)!}{n!}$.

Comment: Yup. I got it after 3 seconds. thx :)

Comment: that is so clean, wow, thanks a lot.

Comment: I got the same answer in your second line, but without $(2n+2)$, how did you get it?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: $\frac{2n+2}{n+1}=2$.

Comment: I like the solution, but it's a result, if I'm not mistaken, based on the fact that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to A$ implies $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to A$, haven't gone over it in our analysis, unfortunately.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I can't seem to understand how you did the first line, by any chance can you do it a bit better? I'm so sorry, feeling stupid :(

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n^n}}.$

Comment: I meant the second line (:

Comment: but i got it now, all good ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the idea 1, we can derive the result using the Stirling's approximation $$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}
 $$ hence $$\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{n!}}\sim\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^{n}}=\frac{2^{2+1/2n}}{e}\rightarrow\frac{4}{e}.
 $$

Comment: In case you saw it, I had a comment - which I have deleted, as it stupid... Sorry! (+1)

Comment: @peterag Yes I saw it, but no problem. Time ago my teacher of history of mathematics told me that Euler, in some notes, wrote some trivial errors. So every mathematician, even the greater, write sooner or later something wrong ;)

Answer (score 3):

Start with the expression on the right of your Idea #2. Using $\ln (n+k)=\ln n + \ln (1+k/n)$ for each $k$ shows that expression equals

$$-\ln n+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\ln n +\ln (1+k/n )]
$$ $$= -\ln n+\frac{1}{n}[n\ln n +  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln (1+k/n )]= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln (1+k/n )$$ $$ \to \int_0^1 \ln (1+x)\, dx = 2\ln2 -1 = \ln (4/e).$$

Exponentiating back gives $4/e$ for the limit.

Comment: Aha, Riemann integrability, yes? Elaborate on limits of integration please.

Comment: I'm just using $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n)\cdot (1/n) \to \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.$

Comment: (+1) This is the way I would have pursued just because it uses basic tools that even an entry-level student would be able to apply.