# How to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n(n + i)} = \frac{4}{e}$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n(n + i)} = \frac{4}{e}$ ?

First, I try $$\begin{align}
A_n &= \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n(n + i)} \\
\ln(A_n) &= \ln\left(\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n(n + i)}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(n + i) \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln\left(n\left(1 + \frac{i}{n}\right)\right)\ldots\star \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(n) + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1 + \frac{i}{n}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n}n\ln(n) + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1 + \frac{i}{n}\right) \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(A_n)&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n) + \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1 + \frac{i}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n} \\
\end{align}$$
That does not work because the first RHS term $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n)$ goes to $\infty$. That is also the case if I factor out $i$ instead of $n$ at the step marked with $\star$.

Is there another way?

Comment: I guess you made a mistake in the problem because right now you have $A_n \ge \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(n+0)} = n $ so it diverges.

Comment: You probably mean  $\lim_{n \to \infty} {1 \over n}  \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n (n+i)}$, in which case this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527165/homework-limit-of-frac1n-sqrtn-prod-k-1nnk-as-n-to-infty?rq=1 .

Comment: However, $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{n+i}{n} } \ \frac4e$$ so maybe that was what the problem intended.

Comment: I double checked the problem sheet, and what I wrote is identical to the one on the problem sheet. But, I checked with the following C program and found that $A_n$ diverges. So, yes, you are all correct, the problem is wrong. The C program: #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) { double prod = 1; int n = atoi(argv[1]); for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) prod *= pow(n + i, 1.0/n); printf("%f\n", prod - 4.0 / exp(1)); return 0; }